# Can not install the package bsselectR

Tags: r

Firstly I tried

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("walkerke/bsselectR")
```

I got the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) :    Could not
>   resolve host: api.github.com

Then I tried to install the package from zip

```
install.packages("C:/Users/my/Downloads/bsselectR-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

No error or warning.But when `library` it I get an error

```
> library(bsselectR)
```

> Error in library(bsselectR) :   There is no package called 'bsselectR'

What should I do?

[walkerke/bsselectR](https://github.com/walkerke/bsselectR)

---

**Solution**

The easiest way I found to install from zip file:

1.Download the zip and decompress it.

2.Copy the path of decompressed file (folder which has DESCRIPTION file).

3.Do it with function `install_local` from `devtools`

```
library("devtools")
install_local("path/to/the/decompressed/folder/which has DESCRIPTION file")
```

4.`library` it

Comment: `Could not resolve host: api.github.com` is probably that you lost your internet connection. Please try again

Comment: Or you have some proxy issue. See [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1414#issuecomment-259034930)